# Можно ли в модель включить ссылку на объект базового класса?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Упрощенный пример структуры моделей для БД:

```
class Base { // в идеале абстрактный класс
    // ...
}

class A_Base : Base {
    // ...
}

class B_Base : Base {
    // ...
}
```

Хотелось бы получить возможность сделать так:

```
class SomeOtherClass {
    public Base BaseInstance { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо обеспечить возможность добавлять в поле BaseInstance сущности типов `A_Base` или `B_Base`.

Возможно ли это? Как настроить DBСontext?

Comment: Вы пробовали уже? Какая-то ошибка возникла?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пробовал. Мучался долго. Вся загвоздка была в настройках + месте где они выполнены. Почему то EF core не воспринимал некоторые настройки выполненные в классе реализующем EntityTypeConfiguration.